# Concatenating vectors for CNN in Keras/tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I am trying to concatenate the flattened output of a CNN, and a vector of scalar values. I am trying to influence the network by both the image and the vector. So the output of the flattened CNN size is `(1,1024)`, and the vector I want to concatenate is `(1,5)`.

Of course keras wants them to be similar sizes. So what is the best practice in this situation? Expand the vector to `1024` with zeroes? I am trying to make the vector have an impact, what other options can I do? I am trying to do something similar to here (https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02199).

Answer (score 1):

Why not concatenating them over the last dimension, to obtain a tensor of shape `(1, 1029)`?

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate

img = Input(shape=(1,1024))
vec = Input(shape=(1,5))
res = Concatenate(axis=-1)([img, vec])
model = Model(inputs=[img, vec], outputs=res)
model.summary()
# _______________________________________________________________________________
# Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
# ===============================================================================
# input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 1, 1024)      0              
# _______________________________________________________________________________
# input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 1, 5)         0              
# _______________________________________________________________________________
# concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 1, 1029)      0           input_1[0][0]
#                                                                  input_2[0][0]
# ===============================================================================
# Total params: 0
# Trainable params: 0
# Non-trainable params: 0
# _______________________________________________________________________________
```